# Can you use the two unarmed strikes from flurry of blows to use a throwing weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, monk

When using the flurry of blows, can you use the two unarmed strikes you get from flurry of blows to throw monk weapons?

The Martial arts features gives the option of using the attack action for an unarmed strike or a monk weapons, is that only for the martial art or does it apply to unarmed strikes for the monk in general
?

Comment: Well, you've said yourself "*attack* action for unarmed strike or a monk weapons". Unarmed strike != attack action. Why do you think that they are interchangeable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No.**

Flurry of Blows (PHB, p.78)

> Immediately after you take the Attack action on your
>   turn, you can spend 1 ki point to make two **unarmed strikes** as a bonus action.

Any kind of weapon attack, thrown or otherwise, is *by definition* not an unarmed strike.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can only use the armed strikes allowed by Flurry of Blows for unarmed strikes.  An unarmed strike is by definition an attack without a weapon.

> **Flurry of Blows**
>   Immediately after you take the Attack action on your turn, you can spend 1 ki point to make two unarmed strikes as a bonus action.